# Cant make campaigns in cordova work with analytics v4

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-analytics, cordova-plugins

I am trying to make campaigns for my Cordova app.

I am using this plugins:

https://github.com/Anu2g/google-analytics-plugin.git Which have support for campaigns

https://github.com/8zrealestate/android-referrer-plugin.git For retrieve the referrer, so I can not find the way to get it in the analytics plugin

https://github.com/chrisekelley/AppPreferences.git To get the refferrer saved in the app preferences into my javascript.

For context, i am using Cordova 4.3.0 and google analytics v4

My manifests looks like this:

```
<receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.eightz.mobile.cordova.plugin.android.referrer.Receiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And I am trying to follow this guide to make it work:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns

I have tryied with and without this service in the manifest

```
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
 android:enabled="true"
 android:exported="false"/>
```

I also have tried all kind of am broadcasts

```
    am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER \
-n my.app/com.eightz.mobile.cordova.plugin.android.referrer.Receiver \
--es "referrer" "textinreferrer"
```

They work, they return

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER cmp=my.app/com.eightz.mobile.cordova.plugin.android.referrer.Receiver (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

But in the logcat I get CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered error, even with the app closed.

I have also tryied with GAv3 and GAv4 receivers, but I am unable to make the campaignTrackingReceiver work, i am still getting

```
CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered, not exported or is disabled. Installation campaign tracking is not possible. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.
```

Or simply nothing.

somebody have any ideas? I am missing something? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you already tried https://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google-adid (which integrages https://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google). It is all-in-one plugin for your needs.

Comment: I am looking at it, but i dont see nothing about campaings. My goal is to track email campaigns. EDIT: Ok, I see it, but I have the sale problem. How can I retrieve the campaign URL to the javascript to include in the tracks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, the problem is that I had two receivers, and Android messes it. With this solution and the three plugins, you are able to track campaigns with real data in Cordova. The log dont work very well, but you can see the real path debugging the javascript. Good luck.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns says: "If your application has two receivers registered for this intent, it is recommended that you create a custom receiver that can receive the INSTALL_REFERRER intent and dispatch it to other receivers, including the Google Analytics receiver, as necessary". How do you dispatch it to the google's receiver? Or does the eightz's plugin do it for us?